# Manual swith back to normal Website on mobile Device using wurfl

Tags: javascript, jquery, wurfl

I can't get into it. Please give me a hint.
There is a website with device-detection with wurfl - the javascript method.
The condition looks like this:

```
if(!WURFL.is_mobile){
$('body').addClass('mobile'); //Do the stuff for mobile website
} else {
$('body').addClass('no-mobile'); // Do the stuff for no-mobile normal website
};
```

Now we want to put a button on mobile Version to switch back to normal (no-mobile) Website manualy. But the website needs to be reloaded without care of the orginal wurfl-condition, because there are some images and html inserted with javascrit on the normal (no-mobile) Version. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the button is pressed to manually go to mobile or desktop, you can set a cookie like so:

`document.cookie = "forceMobile=true";`

then just read the cookie in your if statement like so:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

if(!WURFL.is_mobile && !getCookie("forceMobile")) ...
```

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Hello jdmdevdotnet, Thank you! Yes - you show me the right direction. I found the "localStorrage" cappabillity. What do you think, Mabe sone users have cookies deactivated.

Comment: Yes! Welcome to one of the many issues we have to deal with (people disabling cookies, javascript..etc). That's a choice you have to make as a developer, do you support them? Some sites don't let you onto the site if you have cookies blocked for instance. In my experience, we use cookies in situations EXACTLY like this, and if they have them blocked, then it simply won't work. If they emailed us, we'd tell them our site relies on cookies to properly work.